# better phrase or idiom for "run panickedly"

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

> The boy is chased by bees and he **runs panickedly**

Is there a better phrase or idiom that more can replace **runs panickedly** to make the sentence more vivid?

Comment: He runs, in a panic...(_Panickedly_ is an awfully ugly word - and isn't in Oxford Dictionaries.)

Comment: Just avoid "...chased by bees and flees."

Answer (score 1):

> The boy is chased by bees and he runs panickedly

The most idiomatic version in my opinion is:

*The boy is chased by bees **and he panics and runs**.*

Answer (score 0):

I think the most idiomatic equivalent would be "**runs for his life**".  It's a common phrase, it captures the emotion, and everyone will understand that the boy probably wouldn't actually die if caught.

Answer (score 0):

I think the version most similar to your original sentence structure of `runs <adverb>` is:

> The boy is chased by bees and he **runs frantically**

Answer (score 0):

The problems with **panickedly** are that a) it's a made-up word b) it doesn't sound very elegant c) it's an adverb, so it describes the **way** that the boy runs. What you most likely want to do is to describe the **state** of the boy as he runs. The neatest way to say this would be to use a participle phrase (of just one word):

> The boy is chased by bees and he runs, panicked.

Here, panicked describes the state of the boy, not the way that he runs.